# how can I make this query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

edit: here is a simplified version of the original query (runs in 3.6 secs on a products table of 475K rows)

```
SELECT p.*, shop FROM products p JOIN
users u ON p.date >= u.prior_login and u.user_id = 22 JOIN
shops s ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id
ORDER BY shop, date, product_id;
```

this is the explain plan

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  u   const   PRIMARY,prior_login,user_id PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  s   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    90   
1   SIMPLE  p   ref shop_id,date,shop_id_2,shop_id_3    shop_id 4   bitt3n_minxa.s.shop_id  5338    Using where
```

the bottleneck seems to be `ORDER BY date,product_id`. Removing these two orderings, the query runs in 0.06 seconds. (Removing either one of the two (but not both) has virtually no effect, query still takes over 3 seconds.) I have indexes on both product_id and date in the products table. I have also added an index on (product,date) with no improvement.

newtover suggests the problem is the fact that the `INNER JOIN users u1 ON products.date >= u1.prior_login` requirement is preventing use of the index on products.date

Two variations of the query that execute in ~0.006 secs (as opposed to 3.6 secs for the original) have been suggested to me (not from this thread).

this one uses a subquery, which appears to force the order of the joins

```
SELECT p.*, shop 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT p.*
    FROM products p 
    WHERE p.date >= (select prior_login FROM users where user_id = 22)
  ) as p
  JOIN shops s 
    ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id
  ORDER BY shop, date, product_id;
```

this one uses the WHERE clause to do the same thing (although the presence of SQL_SMALL_RESULT doesn't change the execution time, 0.006 secs without it as well)

```
SELECT SQL_SMALL_RESULT p . * , shop
FROM products p
INNER JOIN shops s ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id
WHERE p.date >= ( 
SELECT prior_login
FROM users
WHERE user_id =22 ) 
ORDER BY shop, DATE, product_id;
```

My understanding is that these queries work much faster on account of reducing the relevant number of rows of the product table before joining it to the shops table. I am wondering if this is correct.

Comment: by the way, where do multiple product_id rows come from that you need to sort on `circle_favorited`?

Comment: @newtover multiple friends of the user can favorite the same product, so each different friend who favorites a product with a given product_id generates a new row containing that product_id (and the friend's username). Each row in the favorites table contains a user_id and a binary favorite value. If this value is 0, this means the user voted the product down. If this value is 1, the user voted the product up. I sort by circle_favorited in order to separate those users who voted the product up from those who voted it down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `EXPLAIN` statement to see the execution plan. Also you can try adding an index to `products.date` and `u1.prior_login`.

Also please just make sure you have defined your foreign keys and they are indexed.

Good luck.

Comment: I added an explain plan above. Adding indices on date and prior_login did not change the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

We do need an explain plan... but

Be very careful of select * from table where id in (select id from another_table)  This is a notorious.  Generally these can be replaced by a join.  The following query might run, although I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT shop,
       shops.shop_id AS shop_id,
       products.product_id AS product_id,
       brand,
       title,
       price,
       image AS image,
       image_width,
       image_height,
       0 AS sex,
       products.date AS date,
       fav1.favorited AS circle_favorited,
       fav2.favorited AS session_user_favorited,
       u2.username AS circle_username
  FROM products
       LEFT JOIN favorites fav2
          ON     fav2.product_id = products.product_id
             AND fav2.user_id = 22
             AND fav2.current = 1
       INNER JOIN shops
          ON shops.shop_id = products.shop_id
       INNER JOIN users u1
          ON products.date >= u1.prior_login AND u1.user_id = 22
       LEFT JOIN favorites fav1
          ON products.product_id = fav1.product_id
       LEFT JOIN friends f1
          ON f1.star_id = fav1.user_id
       LEFT JOIN users u2
          ON fav1.user_id = u2.user_id
 WHERE f1.fan_id = 22 OR fav1.user_id = 22
ORDER BY shop,
         DATE,
         product_id,
         circle_favorited
```

Comment: thanks, I've added an explain plan above, will test your query presently

Comment: your query is only producing 7 results, instead of the 497 of the original. I believe this is on account of the WHERE clause, which is limiting the results to only those cases in which (f1.fan_id = 22 OR fav1.user_id = 22), when this will not be the case for most products. If I move these criteria to make them part of the `LEFT JOIN friends f1` declaration, it looks like I am getting a duplicate row for a product when the user has favorited that product (ie two rows with the circle username as the session user for that product), which did not happen in the original query. Query took 3.7 secs.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the explain plan that really strikes me as outrageous.  What I would suggest is building the query up table by table and finding what's causing the biggest performance hit.  It shouldn't take too long, since you already have a functional query.

Comment: I followed your advice and found the execution time goes to 0.06 secs when I remove `ORDER BY product_id, date`. (If I order by either product_id, date, or both, the query takes about the same amount of time, over 3 seconds.) I have indices on product_id and date so I'm puzzled how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a combined index on product_id and date (column order matters, so try both)  That's not the same as having separate indexes on product_id and date

Comment: I added a combined index on product_id and date, but the query still executes in ~3.5 secs when using `ORDER BY products.date`, `ORDER BY products.product_id` or a combination of the two. Incidentally I noticed that if I run the same query twice in phpMyAdmin, it executes in 0.0001 secs the second time. I'm wondering if this is the result of caching, and if so, if there's some way to turn it off, since it makes it hard to benchmark the query. (edit: I found out it's SQL_NO_CACHE, so now I am reliably getting ~3.5 secs for each execution)

Answer (score 0):

the fact that the query is slow because of the ordering is rather obvious since it is hard to find an index that would to apply ORDER BY in this case. The main problem is  `products.date >=` comparison which breaks using any index for ORDER BY. And since you have a lot of data to output, MySQL starts using temporary tables for sorting.

what i would to is to try to force MySQL output data in the order of an index which already has the required order and remove the ORDER BY clause.

I am not at a computer to test, but how would I do it:

- I would do all inner joins
- then I would LEFT JOIN to a subquery which makes all computations on favorites ordered by product_id, circle_favourited (which would provide the last ordering criterion).

So, the question is how to make the data be sorted on shop, date, product_id

I am going to write about it a bit later =)

UPD1:

You should probably read something on how btree indexes work in MySQL. There is a good article on mysqlperformanceblog.com about it (I currently write from a mobile and don't have the link at hand). In short, you seem to talk about one-column indexes which arrange pointers  to rows based on values sorted in a single column. Compound indexes store an order based on several columns. Indexes mostly used to operate on clearly defined ranges of them to obtain most of the information before retrieving data from the rows they point at. Indexes usually do not know about other indexes on the same table, as result they are rarely merged. when there is no more info to take from the index, MySQL starts to operate directly on data.

That is an index on date can not make use of the index on product_id, but an index on (date, product_id) can get some more info on product_id after a condition on date (sort on product id for a specific date match).

Nevertheless, a range condition on date (>=) breaks this. That is what I was talking about.

UPD2:

As I uderstand the problem can be reduced to (most of the time it spends on that):

```
SELECT p.*, shop
FROM products p
JOIN users u ON p.`date` >= u.prior_login and u.user_id = 22
JOIN shops s ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id
ORDER BY shop, `date`, product_id;
```

Now add an index (user_id, prior_login) on users and (date) on products, and try the following query:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN p.*, shop
FROM (
  SELECT product_id, shop
  FROM users u
  JOIN products p
    user_id = 22 AND p.`date` >= prior_login
  JOIN shops s
    ON p.shop_id = s.shop_id
  ORDER BY shop, p.`date`, product_id
) as s
JOIN products p USING (product_id);
```

If I am correct the query should return the same result but quicker. If would be nice if you would post the result of EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, the problem is that I cannot both use products.date to limit the results if I want to use the index on products.date. I am very interested in learning how to do the sorting without ORDER BY. So far I can't figure it out.

Comment: also I'm curious why `ORDER BY product_id` also causes the bottleneck even though this is not involved in the `products.date >=` comparison

Comment: unfortunately, that query runs at the same speed as the original, roughly 3.5 secs. I did create an index ('shop_id,date') on the products table. perhaps some other index is required?

Comment: also, I notice that if I remove `JOIN users u ON p.`date` >= u.prior_login and u.user_id = 22` from the reduced query (the first one in your answer), the query takes almost exactly double the time to execute (over seven seconds). The query without this JOIN retrieves 475K rows (versus ~1K for the query with the JOIN). Does this suggest that the JOIN is not interfering with the indexing?

Comment: @jela, I updated the last query. Try this one and show the EXPLAIN. You may just provide a link to it on pastebin, I would just like to take a look.

Comment: that updated query executes in the same time as the original, about 3.6 seconds. (I added an ON after `JOIN products p`.) here is the explain http://pastebin.com/SYKMkUhn. Also I now have two working solutions to this problem (now posted in the question), although I am not completely certain I understand why they work.